# Text selection (not built-in but useful) shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, text

We all now we can select all text (in a text area) in any app by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. And this feature is also available for a lot of other contexts such as file selection (in finder for ex), content selection (in photoshop for ex) etc... But in those other contexts you can also perform a *multiple selection* and an *inverted selection* among other stuff.

In the same way for **text** I would find very useful **having shortcuts** to be able to

- **select multiple non-continuous text strings** (I believe you can do this in Microsoft Word). 
  I understand that might be complex to achieve in a rich text area. But how about a plain text area?
- **"invert" the selected text as well**, the same way as we do in Photoshop for a layer for example.

I know there is no built-in way to do this (either on mac or windows). But I wasn't able to find any method/trick to achieve it in my own custom way either (using 3rd-party apps, scripts).

Could anyone enlighten me on this please, especially on Mac?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to select disparate, non-contiguous text in Apple's TextEdit: Just hold down the `command key` while highlighting each desired string with the mouse/trackpad. This action works with both plain text and rich text.

Here's a screen capture showing some arbitrary selections of discontinuous text made in this manner:
[image]

It's also easy to invert the selection: Click-and-drag the cursor over the chosen text while holding down the command key. Here's the same text after making the change:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for these tips on TextEdit, didn't knew them. Well this answers mainly my request. But I was looking for a more flexible way: how would you do this in a browser HTML document or in URL bar?
Of course I figured, you would copy/paste your text TextEdit > then use the described tips from here. But in this case I might as well, use a clipboard app, to copy several strings and paste them in my willing order.

The whole purpose is for productivity. For example, to transform text lowercase/UPPERCASE and vice versa using shortcuts I used this extension: https://tinyurl.com/y9zalwgp